# how to use ResponsiveGridView.builder() in responsive_framework in flutter?

Tags: flutter, responsiveness

1. how to use **gridDeligate** inside **ResponsiveGridView.builder()** in *responsive_framework* package.

   ```
       padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: ResponsiveValue(
              context,
              defaultValue: 10,
              valueWhen: [
                Condition.largerThan(name: MOBILE, value: 20),
                Condition.largerThan(name: TABLET, value: 85),
              ],
            ).value!.toDouble(),
            vertical: 0),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 8,
        gridDelegate: ResponsiveGridDelegate(
          crossAxisSpacing: 50,
          mainAxisSpacing: 50,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
          child: NewsCardWidget(),
        ),
      )),
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use it with a `ResponsiveGridView`.

```
ResponsiveGridView.builder(
          itemCount: controller.tools.length,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          gridDelegate: ResponsiveGridDelegate(
              crossAxisSpacing: 50,
              mainAxisSpacing: 50,
              minCrossAxisExtent: 150),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
              ToolCard(controller.tools[index]),
        )
```